Know if ng-content is empty Angular 17
I have this simple card component.
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>
          <ng-content select="[card-title]"></ng-content>
      </mat-card-title>

      <mat-card-subtitle>
          <ng-content select="[card-subtitle]"></ng-content>
      </mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>

    <mat-card-content>
      <ng-content select="[card-content]"></ng-content>
    </mat-card-content>

    <mat-card-actions>
      <ng-content select="[card-actions]"></ng-content>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>

Question:
How can I get a boolean in my ts file for each ng-content based on if it's empty or not ?
Tried with ContentChild,ContentChildren and ViewChild but it was alaways undefined/empty whether or not it's actually empty.

Are you trying to get value from the parent component?

Well I guess this is where I could get the value so yes

You can specify both types,

[foo] attribute selector -> needed for ng-content
#foo templateRef variable -> needed for @ContentChild.

By doing this, we can perform an if check on the content child and conditionally show the HTML
If your content is a component, then it's easy. We can just do:
@ContentChild(SomeComponent) cardTitle!: any;

PARENT:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { ChildComponent } from './app/child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  template: `
    <app-child><div card-title #cardTitle>Hello from Angular!</div></app-child>
    <br/>
    <app-child/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

CHILD:
import { Component, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `
  @if(!!cardTitle) {
    <ng-content select="[card-title]"/>
  }@else {
    <div> Child not found! </div>
  }
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @ContentChild('cardTitle') cardTitle!: any;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.cardTitle);
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Exactly what I was looking for ! I was missing the templateRef variable
